# SOAPFactory creating 'null' value for 'soap' namespace in addressing header tag

Tags: java, soap, namespaces

From within a J2EE application running in JBoss4.2.3 we are creating a SOAPConnection to invoke a 3rd party's web service.  Inside the SOAP Header we have to set the Addressing To and Action tags, with 'mustUnderstand' set to '1'.  This 'mustUnderstand' attribute is in the `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` namespace.  We create this by calling:

`SOAPFactory#createName("mustUnderstand", "soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");`

This comes out correctly *when we include saaj.jar and saaj-impl.jar in our WEB-INF/lib folder*.  If I take these out, the namespace comes out null as: xmlns:soap='null' instead of `xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`.  Here's the entire bad tag:

`<wsa:To xmlns:wsa='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing' xmlns:soap='null' soap:mustUnderstand='1'>http://domain/web-service.url</wsa:To>`.

But if we have those 2 jar files deployed with the app, our own hosted web-services fail when creating Faults (due to a class-cast exception:

`javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl)`

Our J2EE app is a JBossWS web-service that invokes 3rd-party web-services itself.  There is an apparent conflict with the jar files.

Any ideas on how to get the `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope` namespace to be written out in the generated SOAP tag?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the API directly to call SOAPHeaderElement#mustUnderstand(true).  This looks to have solved this issue since another namespace declaration isn't needed (it uses the soap-env namespace declaration from teh envelope itself.

I still have another issue (JBoss wants to send a chunked HTTP request, which the 3rd party web-service isn't liking, but I haven't looked far enough into that one yet)